# How to create an if/else statement in R based on an open file condition?

Tags: r, file

I've created this function to open a file in `R`:

```
openfasta<-function(DNAseq){
  DNASeq <- readline(prompt = "Enter the .fasta file name:")
  readLines(DNASeq)
```

Now if the file can not be found in the working directory, the script must output a
warning message and ask for the file name repetitively until the file is located.

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
if (DNASeq) {
  return()
  }
  else {
    cat(DNASeq <- readline(prompt = "Enter the .fasta file name:"))
  }
}
```

I think if a For loop would be a reasonable solution too.

Comment: take a look at the function  `file.exists`

Comment: Do you mean using ```file.exists``` with if/else?

Comment: For more 'tips' on how to handle this task and account for edge cases, I suggest you look at the [`read.fasta()` function from the seqinr package](https://github.com/cran/seqinr/blob/master/R/read.fasta.R)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `while` loop to check for file existence. If not found use a `print` statement to display a warning and prompt again.

```
openfasta <- function(DNAseq){
   while(!file.exists(DNAseq)){
        print("The file you requested was not found.")
      
        DNASeq <- readline(prompt = "Enter the .fasta file name:")
    }
  readLines(DNASeq)
  }
```